# Sound becomes loud randomly on laptop

Tags: windows-10, audio, drivers

This is a pretty weird problem. Usually when I am opening new apps or new tabs in a browser or refreshing a page and so on the sound may become very loud. As I found out so far it makes the volume higher even though windows displays the previous level in settings. I usually keep it at 30% so these random jumps are very obvious and annoying. Random means I do not know what causes them but they appear in every window app frequently(like 60% of the time). What I mean is I have never experienced this bug in fullscreen apps/games but AIPM or Chrome may cause this problem. But still, bug cannot be triggered listening to the music in the static tab, the tab needs to be refreshed to make it happen or the other tab/program needs to be opened.

The temporal fix for this isn't convenient either. I need to change the volume so that it is back to MY settings which were changed during bug actions. So I simply can drag volume slider or use my functional buttons to fix it until it happens again.

Update to a newer version of the sound driver did nothing. I experience this problem for more than a year already. All the drivers were taken from dell.com official website.

Any possible fix for this? Thanks for attention!

---

*Additional information:*

- *System: Windows 10 Pro x64 (last updates installed)*
- *Laptop: Dell Vostro 5470*
- *Driver: Realtek High Definition Audio*
- *Version:
  6.0.1.7509 (I downgraded it to lower version trying to fix this, but bug is still present)*

---

*Edit: more information as well as partial fix*

*Ok. This thing is really weird. So when I reinstalled drivers the sound became robotic so I decided to fix that again. I deleted drivers without manually installing new so Windows 10 installed its own drivers and sound became normal, moreover, the bug disappeared. But Windows also decided to install Realtek application later called "Realtek High Definition Audio Driver" which isn't the same as the driver itself, because it worked perfectly without this thing. After Windows reboot the application was already installed and bug returned... At least voice isn't robotic :) So now I am here to ask if there is any way to disallow Windows to install that application from update center? I don't want that buggy thing on my laptop.*

Comment: I once troubleshooted a similar issue. There was a headset with volume control attached to the system that apparently somehow altered the volume. Do you have anything with a volume control attached to your system? Or any USB device that can be used for music, such as a normal USB headphones? Does the problem still occur if you disconnect these devices?

Comment: @LPChip thx for the quick response! I usually listen to music with my earbuds, but this bug may trigger even without anything connected to the laptop...